# It is necessary to update Unity to version 4.5 to release a game for iOs 8?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ios8

Releasing a game for iOS 8, it is absolutely necessary to upgrade Unity 3d to 4.5 version? I have read there are some problems with the rotation of the device, but apart from that, is it mandatory for any reason?

Comment: Here's a thought: build and deploy on a device with iOS 8 installed using your current version of Unity. Look for any issues. If there aren't any you don't have to upgrade for your project specifically.

Comment: Thanks, LearnCocos2D.